# How to display a message box in C# as system modal?

Tags: c#, vb6

How to display a message box in C# as system modal, something like `vbModal` in Visual Basic 6?

Answer (score 3):

[Advanced MessageBoxing with the C# MessageBoxIndirect Wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/MessageBoxIndirectCS.aspx)

Comment: Which is the same link as I posted ;)

Answer (score 2):

Are you talking about message boxes, or standard forms? If you're talking about standard forms, the easiest .NET equivalent of [vbModal](http://spazioinwind.libero.it/vbprogzone/tutorials/forms3.html) is the [ShowDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe.aspx) method of `System.Windows.Forms.Form`. So, rather than the old

```
myForm.Show vbModal
```

you use

```
myForm.ShowDialog();
```

or

```
myForm.ShowDialog(myFormOwner);
```

This halts execution at the `ShowDialog` line just like the old `vbModal` used to.

Comment: These are application modal not system modal

Comment: Yep. He mentioned vbModal, so I'm hoping he doesn't actually *mean* system modal, and more means "on top of all other windows in my app" :-) It's worth a shot anyway, and people searching for vbModal might learn something at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to roll your own.

A quick search has turned up these two links:

[Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/MessageBoxIndirectCS.aspx)

[Egghead Cafe](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30306629/system-modal-message-boxe.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should also be asking yourself if you really want to be creating a system modal message box, its considered bad UI design and that's why its not in .NET out the box.

Answer (score -1):

Standard message box in C# is modal (cannot access rest of app until messagebox is dismissed).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335423(VS.71).aspx

"A message box is a modal dialog, which means no input (keyboard or mouse click) can occur except to objects on the modal form. "

Edit: I am not sure about Vb6 and messagebox there. Does it use a different type of "modal"?

Comment: This is referring to application modal not system modal