# Display an alert/toast while Windows desktop is disabled

Tags: c#, .net, windows, desktop

I want a small application that displays a message to the user while the rest of the desktop is disabled until the user clicks on a button. I am looking for something like the one Windows uses to prompt force closure a not responding process during its shutdown routine . I would like to write it in C#.
Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you looked into [Messagebox.show()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa335415%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)? edit: Sorry, didn't realize you wanted the entire UI blocked as well.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for a [system modal dialog](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3999998/2065121)?

Comment: Yep that's pretty much what I was asking. Thanks for pointing that out.